# LibGit2Sharp stuck on cloning

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I'm using LibGit2Sharp to connect to a log repository to upload log files

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var currentPath = @"C:\TestFolder";
        
        var logsPath = Path.Combine(currentPath, "._LogRepo");
        var repoPath = string.Empty;
       
        if (!Repository.IsValid(logsPath))
        {
            var cloneOpt = new CloneOptions
            {
                CredentialsProvider = (ur, us, ce) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials
                {
                    Username = "MyUser",
                    Password = ("Some App password from bitbucket")
                },
                OnTransferProgress = onTransfer,
                CertificateCheck = onCertCheck,
                OnProgress = onProgress,
                 
                
            };
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start cloning logs repository...");
                repoPath = Repository.Clone("https://MyUser@bitbucket.org/MySite/MyGit.git", logsPath, cloneOpt);
                Console.WriteLine($"Logs repository was creatd in {repoPath}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
           
        }
        else
        {
            repoPath = Repository.Init(logsPath);
        }
        var repo = new Repository(repoPath);
        var info = repo.Info;
        var commits = repo.Commits;
        var cs = commits.ToList();
        if (cs.Any())
        {
            foreach (var commit in cs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(commit.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No commits");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("press to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool onProgress(string serverProgressOutput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(serverProgressOutput);
        return true;
    }

    private static bool onCertCheck(Certificate certificate, bool valid, string host)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"onCertCheck valid:{valid}");
        return valid;
    }

    private static bool onTransfer(TransferProgress progress)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Transfer {progress.ReceivedObjects} {progress.TotalObjects}");
        return true;
    }

    static SecureString StringToSecureString(string str)
    {
        var chars = str.ToCharArray();

        var secure = new SecureString();
        for (var i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            secure.AppendChar(chars[i]);
        }

        secure.MakeReadOnly();

        return secure;
    }
```

Code was taken from the github test examples.

the problem is that the `Repository.Clone` is getting stuck. I was able to get results only 2 times. meaning problem is not the username and password.
when running the app I get

```
Start cloning logs repository...
onCertCheck valid:True
onCertCheck valid:True
```

and nothing....

I also tried to replace the certificate with

```
 CredentialsProvider = (ur, us, ce) => new SecureUsernamePasswordCredentials
                {
                    Username = "MyUser",
                    Password = StringToSecureString("Some App password from bitbucket")
                },
```

everytime I'm running the app I cleaning the `_LogRepo` folder.

Comment: FYI - currently I did wordaround, I working directly with the `git clone` command  and then work with the library.